# javascript dynamic data control error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic, controls

( not access dynamic controls when document.getelementbyId('textStopDesc11') a using function what can ı do?)

function:

```
AddPlannedStop()

{

var table = document.getElementById('tblPlannedStop');
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var hidden = document.getElementById("hftblPlannedStoprowCount");
hidden.value = rowCount;


var btnDeleteIcon = "Images/deleteicon.png";
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML ="<INPUT id='button" + (rowCount-1) + 0 +
"'onclick = 'deletePlannedStopRow()' style='WIDTH: 100%;" +
"BACKGROUND-POSITION: center; BACKGROUND-COLOR: menu;" +
"BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(" + btnDeleteIcon + ")' type='button'>"; 
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var element2 = document.createElement("input");
element2.type = "text";
element2.name = "txtStopDesc" + (rowCount - 1) + 1;
element2.id = rowCount + 1;
element2.style.width = "200px";
cell2.appendChild(element2);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the same method as you reach your table, you are setting the wrong attribute of cell elements. Using dynamic naming for id attribute instead of name could be helpful i guess.

```
element2.id = "txtStopDesc" + (rowCount - 1) + 1;
```